# Android: For loop iterations

Tags: java, android, loops

I am trying to loop through a set of ImageViews to add listeners, I cant remember how to loop through and add a number within the text?

```
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    //convert to text and add number?                       
    block(i).setOnClickListener(ActivityCheck);
}
```

Comment: _convert to text and add number?_ Please elaborate

Comment: Did you want to say that you want to imprint this number into your ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate through the controls in a `LinearLayout` (and other layouts that extend `ViewGroup`) this way:

```
final LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.yourLayout);

for (int i = 0; i < yourLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Object block = yourLayout.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly.

```
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    //sets the text of block to the string value of the position (1-8)
    block(i).setText(Integer.parseToString(i));
    block(i).setOnClickListener(ActivityCheck);
}
```

Forgive me if I didnt quite understand what you were trying to achieve.